# Adding glow effect to lamp with JQuery

Tags: jquery, effect, glow

I'm coming close to finishing a project for a client, they want glowing lamps hanging from the top of their site.

Problem is, it's got to work in IE6+ otherwise I'd do it in css3

I need to know how to make the glow effect smoothly in Jquery

So Far I've come up with half a solution, with getting JQuery to toggle a background image on and off - this would be good for christmas lights or something, but this is not the glow I am looking for

```
    var glow2 = $('.lamp2');
    setInterval(function(){
    glow2.toggleClass('lampglow');
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the background to fadeIn/Out smoothly? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: can't you use jQuery animate to animate the opacity of the "glow-effect-image"?

Comment: Yes, I want the background to fade in and out smoothly - sorry it wasn't clear I'm rushing loads atm lol - think I'm half way there...

       $(document).ready(function() {
        function glow() {
          $(".lamp1").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1200, 'linear')
                     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1200, 'linear', glow);
        }

        glow();
     });

Comment: Figured it out - pretty simple in the end - two background images overlapped in css, and then take one out with opacity - thanks to Mathieu for the idea - will upload the full answer when it lets me in 8 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/RrZEw/

Or you can even enhance it to better fit your needs like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RrZEw/1/

Be creative! :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - pretty simple in the end - two background images overlapped in css, and then take one out with opacity

```
     <div class="lamp1"></div>
     <div class="lamp1 lampglow1"></div>
     <div class="lamp2"></div>
     <div class="lamp2 lampglow2"></div>
     <div class="lamp3"></div>
     <div class="lamp3 lampglow3"></div>

    .lamp1{position:fixed; top:-100px; left:8%; background:url(/assets/img/lamp.png)     no-repeat; width:200px; height:600px;}
    .lamp2{position:fixed; top:-220px; left:5%; background:url(/assets/img/lamp.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:600px;}
    .lamp3{position:fixed; top:-110px; right:5%; background:url(/assets/img/lamp.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:600px;}

    .lampglow1{background:url(/assets/img/lampglow.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:600px;}
    .lampglow2{background:url(/assets/img/lampglow.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:600px;}
    .lampglow3{background:url(/assets/img/lampglow.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:600px;}


   $(document).ready(function() {
    function pulsate() {
      $(".lampglow1").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 3000, 'linear')
                .animate({opacity: 1}, 3000, 'linear', pulsate);
       $(".lampglow2").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 5000, 'linear')
                .animate({opacity: 1}, 5000, 'linear', pulsate);
       $(".lampglow3").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 4000, 'linear')
                 .animate({opacity: 1}, 4000, 'linear', pulsate);
    }

    pulsate();
 });
```